# JavaFX :Open Acrobat Pdf Reader Inside JavaFX Frame

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm new in JavaFX FrameWork.I want to Create a Frame that will open Pdf File inside the Frame.

My Question is,

Is there any way to open Desktop App Inside JavaFx Frame?

I'm new in JavaFX FrameWork.
[I'm just starting from this place](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/09/javafx-how-to-easily-implement-application-preloader-2/)

**Edit:**

I know how to create Frame Using JavaFx .

Ref [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm).

But I want to run a desktop Applications inside of it like Acrobat Reader.

Can anyone please explain this is possible or not?

Am I searching for a wrong thing for a long time? Please Explain me if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe there is integrated PDF supported into either Java or JavaFX. There are however a number of external libraries such as [jpedal](https://www.idrsolutions.com/jpedal/java-pdf-viewer) that provide embeddable java components for the viewing of pdf documents. You should be able to embed this node within the javafx frame.

1. An alternative solution would be to parse the pdf file into something you can display in your jframe.
2. Another solution can be found [here](https://kbdeveloper.qoppa.com/?p=2973) which even includes a simple guide on setup.
3. Another quick search revealed an open source solution:
   [maven-OpenViewerFX-src](https://github.com/IDRSolutions/maven-OpenViewerFX-src)

Watch the youtube video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZA2AyIZNWY)

**A somewhat hackable workaround, if you want no external Java libraries**

It is possible to display the PDF in the web viewer by utilizing pdf.js, See [this website for the entire details](http://enriquezrene.com/home/index.php/en/javafx-english/showing-pdf-files-on-javafx) . But in short it involves rendering the PDF in a webview component. You could then embed the webview component in your Jframe.